# Confusion regarding a step to solve a limit using Squeeze Theorem.

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I am trying to find the following limit using the Squeeze Theorem:

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} \sqrt[3]x\left(3-\sin^2\left(\frac\pi x\right)\right)$$
I began by writing down the range of $\sin:$
$$-1\leq\sin{x}\leq1$$

But here is where I'm confused, since it is $\sin^2x$ in the original limit, is the next step to square all three parts of the inequality? Or, do you begin with the range of $\sin^2x$?

Comment: By "square all three parts of the inequality" do you mean to claim
$$(-1)^2 \leq \sin x \leq 1^2?$$
Think about what that would imply, and if it is correct.

Comment: $-1\le\sin\left(\frac\pi x\right)\le1$ hence $0\le\sin^2\left(\frac\pi x\right)\le1.$

Comment: $-1\leq \sin^2x\leq 1$ is true, but kind of stupid, because the square of a real number is non-negative, so we can automatically say $0\leq\sin^2 x\leq 1$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for this comment! I wish the author of the book had explained that in the solution steps. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \qquad \quad  0  \leqslant \sin ^2 \frac{\pi}{x} \leqslant 1 \\
& \Rightarrow \quad 0 \geqslant-\sin ^2 \frac{\pi}{x} \geqslant-1 \\
& \Rightarrow \quad 3 \geqslant 3-\sin ^2 \frac{\pi}{x} \geqslant 2 . \\
& \Rightarrow \quad 3 \sqrt[3]{x} \geqslant \sqrt[3]{x}\left(3-\sin ^2 \frac{\pi}{x}\right) \geqslant 2 \sqrt[3]{x}  \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Using $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} 2 \sqrt[3]{x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} 3 \sqrt[3]{x}=0$ and the Squeezing Theorem, we have
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \sqrt[3]{x}\left(3-\sin ^2 \frac{\pi}{x}\right)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can only “square all three parts of an inequality” if the parts are nonnegative. Instead, observe that
$$
 -1 \leq \sin z \leq 1 \iff 0 \leq |\sin z| \leq 1
$$
This means that
$$
    0 \leq |\sin z|^2 \leq 1
$$
Since $|\sin z|^2 = |\sin^2 z| = \sin^2 z$, you have that $0 \leq \sin^2 z \leq 1$.

Comment: That makes sense. But then how come the answer key starts off with $-1\leq-sin^2{x}\leq1$ as the first step to solving this limit?

Comment: I wouldn't make that the first step, but it is true.

Comment: Probably because it implies the second step, which I cannot see. It might help to copy the entire solution into your original question.

Comment: That's alright, I understand the logic of the answer now. Thank you.